# Query on eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have **Book** and **Store** models which have **belongsToMany** relationship.

In Book.php

```
public function stores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Store')->withPivot('qty');
    }
```

In Store.php

```
public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book')->withPivot('qty');
    }
```

Now I just want to know the total number of books in store A and B together. How can I do it with eloquent ORM? I can get all books belonging to store A and B using **whereHas** but cannot go further to aggregate the **qty** field in the pivot table.

Comment: You want the count of store in A, B and the total for each books quantity? Explain further please

Comment: @SapneshNaik
For example store A has 2 of **book-a** and 3 of **book-b**. store B has 3 of **book-a** and 4 of **book-b**
so the result will be
book-a: 5
book-b: 7

Answer (score 0):

So you want the total qty of books by combination of store id and book id

The way you've described your DB structure, it looks like your pivot table has exactly these columns: `book_id`, `store_id` and `qty`

**So all you really need to do is:**

`DB::table('book_stores')->get()`